# Symfony 5.3 - Can't display login error messages

Tags: php, symfony

I used to authenticate users with the guard method, was working perfectly.

Now I try to edit my code to use the [new authenticator-based system](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/authenticator_manager.html) as the old one is dreprecated, everything is working fine except for the error messages.
If wrong credentials, an exception is thrown, I can dump it in the onAuthenticationFailure() method but can't retrieve it from controller with the $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError() method.

Could anyone help me with this please ? The online documentation for this new auth system is quite short for the moment.

**/src/Security/LoginFormAuthenticator.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractAuthenticator;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\RememberMeBadge;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;

use App\Entity\Utilisateur;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security; 

//todelete
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;



class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractAuthenticator
{
    
    use TargetPathTrait;
    
    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';
    
    private $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        
    }
    
    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }
    
    public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );
        
        return new Passport(
                new UserBadge($credentials['email']),
                new PasswordCredentials($credentials['password']),
                [
                    new CsrfTokenBadge('login', $credentials['csrf_token']),
                    new RememberMeBadge()
                ]
            );
        
    }
    
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('index'));
    }
    
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE));
    }
}
```

**/src/Controller/SecurityController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout(): void
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

**/config/packages/security.yaml**

```yaml
    security:
        enable_authenticator_manager: true
        password_hashers:
            App\Entity\Utilisateur:
                algorithm: auto
    
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
        providers:
            # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
            app_user_provider:
                entity:
                    class: App\Entity\Utilisateur
                    property: email
        firewalls:
            dev:
                pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
                security: false
            main:
                #anonymous: true
                lazy: true
                provider: app_user_provider
                
                form_login: ~
                #entry_point: form_login
                custom_authenticators:
                  - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
                #guard:
                  #authenticators:
                    #- App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
                logout:
                  path: app_logout
                remember_me:
                  secret: '%kernel.secret%'
                  lifetime: 31536000
                  path: /
    
                # activate different ways to authenticate
                # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication
    
                # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
                # switch_user: true
    
        # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
        # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
        access_control:
             - { path: ^/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
             - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
            # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: Please clarify what you trying to archive. This code looks like the generated one from symfony.

Comment: If a user tries to log in with wrong credentials, I want to display an error message.
From my controller I try to use $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError() method.

Comment: Looks like you got it working but unless you have a good reason not to then you should consider running bin/console make:auth and selecting 'Login form authenticator' option.  You get a authenticator class that extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator which takes care of the session stuff for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your `LoginFormAuthenticator` to extends `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator` which has a `onAuthenticationFailure` method that store the authentication error in the session, and then you could be able to retrieve it in your own controller, with `$authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError()`